# C# SMO Executenonquery failed for database

Tags: c#, sql, smo

My code lines(I am still a rookie. ) ;
I was trying to export the table on C# so after searching and trying hours I got this problem

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Server server = new Server();

    Database sourceDB = server.Databases["KaynakDB"];
    Table table = sourceDB.Tables["AnaTablo"];

    Database targetDB = server.Databases["KopyaDB"];

    foreach (String query in table.Script())
        try
        {
            targetDB.ExecuteNonQuery(query);
        }
        catch (Exception asd)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(asd.Message);
        }
}
```

Error Message is

```
FailedOperationException was unhandled

An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException' 
occurred in Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
```

When I go to the "Details" page it says **"ExecuteNonQuery failed for Database "KopyaDB"**."

Also the "try-catch" says the same too.

Am I missing something?

Comment: why are you using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management? and where do you set a connectionstring?

Comment: Can you give an overview of what you are trying to do with this code?

Comment: @Kami I am trying to copy my table from Source Database to the Copy one(Without using SQL's Import and Export Wizard.).

Comment: @giammin , connection string is default(local(I've tried with typing it too))
and I just forgot to delete it. (I mean the libary one.)

Comment: @DearCenkay look inside the exception to see what has failed

Comment: @giammin , did you mean "InnerException" ?

Comment: @DearCenkay yes inner and all other properties of the exception. It would be nice for others to say who you resolved it

Answer (score 0):

table.Script() returns a collection of individual line of the query, so you might want to store the them in a StringBuilder first, then execute the query as a whole.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var line in table.Script()){
    sb.AppendLine(line);
}
targetDB.ExecuteNonQuery(sb.ToString());
```

Hope this helps.